# Can Darknet YOLOv4 be used in Windows as a library in Pycharm without compil using CMake?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, darknet, yolov4

I need to use **Darknet YOLOv4** in the **Pycharm project** on **Windows**. Can I use it directly **without compiling using CMake and Visual Studio**? Is there any way to use Darknet YOLOv4 as a library to detect custom images by providing *.cfg, .data,* and *.weights* files for my custom dataset?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, cause python need the darknet DLLs to work.

there is 3 dll file that you need:

- ***yolo_cpp_dll_no_gpu.dll*** for **CPU** use
- ***yolo_cpp_dll*** for **GPU** use

2 others dll files must be in the same path (normally the same path where darknet.py is located

these files are normally renamed as ***darknet.dll***

- ***pthreadGC2.dll***
- ***pthreadVC2.dll***

you can find them [here](https://github.com/sachadee/darknet-compiled-dll-windows-10-64)

compiled and tested on ***win10/64bit***